# Is there a keyboard shortcut to select the failed unit test in the Visual Studio 2012 Test Explorer view?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, keyboard-shortcuts

**Question**

Is there a keyboard shortcut in Visual Studio 2012 to select the failed unit test so I can see the message that goes along with it?

**Problem**

When I run the unit tests, Visual Studio only shows a summary (see screenshot 1).

However, what I am interested in is the failure message (see screenshot 2). And I'd like to get there with a keyboard shortcut, i.e. without touching the mouse.

*Screenshot 1*

The Test Explorer view without any test selected. So only a summary is shown.

[image]

*Screenshot 2*

The Test Explorer view with a failing test selected. Now, I see the failure message.

[image]

Comment: Should probably be on programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0):

You could select a test by traversing the test list using Key Down/Up (either tab or arrow key down to the test list and then use arrow key down/up to select the test you are interested in).

Best wishes,
Qing